# How can I perform C-Style Typecasting in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, type-conversion

Lets say I have the following `np.uint8` array:

```
In [9]: a = np.array([0x34, 0xF3, 0x87, 0x42]).astype(np.uint8)
In [10]: a
Out[10]: array([0x34, 0xf3, 0x87, 0x42], dtype=uint8)
```

Now when I do a conversion to a `np.uint16`, I get the following:

```
In [11]: b = a.astype(np.uint16)
In [12]: b
Out[12]: array([0x34, 0xf3, 0x87, 0x42], dtype=uint16)
```

This is what is expected to happen, but I want something else.
For example, in C, when you have the same array with the type `uint8` (`unsigned char`) and you want to access it as if it were an array containing `uint16` (`unsigned short`) elements:

```
unsigned char a[] = {0x34, 0xF3, 0x87, 0x42};
unsigned short* b = (unsigned short*)a;
```

This will give me, as expected for C:

```
0x34 0xF3 0x87 0x42  // for a
0xF334    0x4287     // for b, little or big endian, for me doesn't matter
```

Now my question is, how can I do this type of thing in Python? (Is it even possible to convert from one type into another type without creating new array?)

I could create a new array by bit shifting and adding two Bytes together like so:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(formatter={'int':hex})

# I assume, a has the len 2*n  and b has the len n (for conversion from 2*n Bytes in n 2Bytes)
a = np.array([0x31, 0x41, 0x59, 0x26, 0x53, 0x58, 0x97, 0x93]).astype(np.uint8)
b = np.array([(a[2*i]<<8)+a[2*i+1] for i in range(0, len(a) // 2)]).astype(np.uint16)

print("a: {}".format(a)) # a: [0x31 0x41 0x59 0x26 0x53 0x58 0x97 0x93]
print("b: {}".format(b)) # b: [0x3141 0x5926 0x5358 0x9793]
```

I need this for very big arrays (more or less), so I'm asking if this is possible to do more efficiently in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't actually advise to do that ([`@user2357112` already explained why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41992630/5393381)) but you can also manually alter (set) the `dtype` attribute:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0x34, 0xF3, 0x87, 0x42]).astype(np.uint8)
>>> a.dtype = np.uint16
>>> a
array([62260, 17031], dtype=uint16)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
b = a.view(np.uint16)
```

This is a dangerous and error-prone operation. Keep in mind all the same caveats you should be keeping in mind in C++, such as endianness. You also need to worry about additional caveats, like noncontiguous array memory layouts. At least strict aliasing is Someone Else's Problem; the implementation probably violates C strict aliasing rules, but hopefully they're setting a compiler flag or something to get defined behavior. (`uint8` is `unsigned char`, so strict aliasing doesn't apply, but `ndarray.view` also allows stuff like `uint64`->`float64` reinterpretation.)

Comment: So basically you would not recommend me to do e.g. b = a.view(np.uint16)? For my problem I will only do the casts from uintX to uintY. Also the little-endian conversion is not a problem. Because I have (to be specific) a S-Box, therefore I need it. Also can I set any flags in Python to get defined behavior? (e.g.for numpy to get big or little endian and so on )

Comment: @PiMathCLanguage: You can [specify the endianness of a dtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html). For example, `np.array(..., dtype='<i2')` would use a dtype of little-endian 2-byte integers, while `dtype='>i2'` would be big-endian.